# Package of Flash memory S25F064L

Tags: flash, soic

I need to use a SPI Flash from Cypress / Infineon to build a prototype for a future product.

The exact model I have ordered is S25FL064LABMFM000.

According to the [seller page](https://www.mouser.fr/ProductDetail/Cypress-Semiconductor/S25FL064LABMFM000?qs=W0yvOO0ixfHDxzJdgUaR0Q%3D%3D) it is a SOIC16 package which is confirmed by the datasheet :

[image]

(there is no other 16 pins package available for this product in the datasheet).

However the memory does not fit in the "SOIC16 to DIL" adaptor that I've bought.

After few research it looks like the memory package is wider than the SOIC16 standard dimensions. Here is a quote from wikipedia:

[image]

Wb is around 7mm on my package.

After a closer look to the datasheet it mentions "16-lead SOIC 300 mil (SO3016)" and 300mil is indeed around 7.5mm.

So my questions are: is this package a standard one ? and is it possible to find a DIL adaptor for it ? (I didn't find one yet, all adaptors for SOIC16 do not mention the IC wide).

Comment: Yes, wide 300-mil SOIC is a standard package. You'll see them more often in devices with a larger number of pins, or in devices like opto-isolators where the extra width gives better isolation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, 16-lead plastic small outline family includes a 300 mil wide package, so it is quite common.

Yes, DIL adaptors exist.